# Difference between today,week start

Tags: python, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

How to get the difference between `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, and the start of week?

I want start of week of
`"date=17,month=12,year=2022,hour=x,minute=y,second=z"` to be:
`"date=12,month=12,year=2022,hour=0,minute=0,second=0"`, where *x,y,z are variables*,while they have to be converted to 0,0,0 only.

I tried the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt,\
    timezone as tz,\
    timedelta as td
print(dt.isoformat(dt.utcnow()-td(days=dt.weekday(dt.now(tz.utc)))))
```

I used iso format to demonstrate what I mean,
for the 'now' value, I gave above,where date=17,
I get the following output:
`"date=12,month=12,year=2022,hour=x,minute=y,second=z"`(not what i expected)

*Q.s Whats the best way to make these hours,minutes,seconds 0,taking into account all **special cases:***

1. A range which includes feb 29, of a leap year
2. A Example where week day is of previous month, of current day
3. etc.

Comment: Note: this is not the final stage, my problem is only on finding start of week, i will manage to find their(now,start of week) difference on my own probably

Comment: What do you mean with "(???)"

Comment: thats the question,i.e. the code to get the proper start of week was the question

Comment: OK, I updated that phrase to make it a question. (*"(???)"* reads like *"what!?"*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td

def getStartOfTheWeekDate(someDate: dt):
    return someDate - td(days=someDate.weekday())

def getDifferenceBetweenMyDateAndStartOfTheWeek(someDate: dt):
    return someDate - getStartOfTheWeekDate(someDate)

myStartOfTheWeek = getStartOfTheWeekDate(dt.now())
myStartOfTheWeekISO = dt.isoformat(myStartOfTheWeek)
myStartOfTheWeekStrippedISO = dt.isoformat(dt.combine(myStartOfTheWeek, dt.min.time()))

myDifference = getDifferenceBetweenMyDateAndStartOfTheWeek(dt.now())

print(myStartOfTheWeek)
print(myStartOfTheWeekISO)
print(myStartOfTheWeekStrippedISO)
print(myDifference)
```

Outputs:

[image: poutput]

Comment: Thanks for that combine, min time in ,start of week stripped, I found the code I needed to be `dt.now() - dt.combine(dt.now() - td(days=dt.now().weekday()), dt.min.time())`